# Using Class Modules to specify different ranges based on sheet name

Tags: excel, class, module, range, vba

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere. I have searched the usual sites and can't find anything that I can bend to suit my needs

I have a workbook with multiple sheets that are in three different formats. eg sheets 1 to 3 are format 1, sheets 4 to 8 are format 2 and so on. I need to extract specific data from each sheet to compile some summary reports. So far I have done this by manually specifying ranges to copy and paste. While this works it is very inelegant and requires a lot of code change if the format ever needs to change.

I have read a little on class modules and think the answer may be in there. I can create new objects (called LineDescriptions, TenderValues, TenderCost and others) as ranges for the elements to copy, so I can set ws1.LineDescriptions in the standard module. What I would like to do is also Set the ranges in the class module, so that if the sheet is 'type 1' the range is ws.Range("B1:B50") and type 2 is ws.Range("C3:C53"). I can't seem to get this to work.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds to me as though named ranges would be more useful to you than class modules.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I suspect you may be right. I might declare them as public ranges or use a function to set ranges based on sheet name. a select statement might work

Comment: Or you could just use the same name on each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Although (as per comments) `Named Ranges` are probably an easier and more elegant solution, here's an example of "Using Class Modules to specify different ranges based on sheet name", as per the question.

Let's say we have a `RangeReturner` class, that you can pass a worksheet.
It then checks the first X (in this example 5) characters of the worksheet name. Based on this sheet name value, it sets it's own "targetRange" property that you can then retrieve from the Class.

```
Private p_ws As Worksheet
Private p_targetRange As Range
Public Property Get SheetToCheck() As Worksheet
    Set SheetToCheck = p_ws
End Property
Public Property Let SheetToCheck(value As Worksheet)
    Set p_ws = value
    Select Case Left(p_ws.Name, 5)
        Case "Type1":
            Set p_targetRange = p_ws.Range("B1:B50")
        Case "Type2":
            Set p_targetRange = p_ws.Range("C3:C53")
        Case Else:
            Set p_targetRange = p_ws.Range("A1") 'Some default, to avoid error on targetRange.
    End Select
End Property
Public Property Get targetRange() As Range
    Set targetRange = p_targetRange
End Property
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
Sub Test()
Dim RR As RangeReturner
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set RR = New RangeReturner
    RR.SheetToCheck = ws
    MsgBox RR.targetRange.Address
Next ws

Set RR = Nothing
End Sub
```

To add the properties you describe, you could do something like the following in the class:

```
Private p_ws As Worksheet
Private p_LineDescriptions As Range
Private p_TenderValues As Range
Public Property Get SheetToCheck() As Worksheet
    Set SheetToCheck = p_ws
End Property
Public Property Let SheetToCheck(value As Worksheet)
    Set p_ws = value
    Select Case Left(p_ws.Name, 5)
        Case "Type1":
            Set p_LineDescriptions = p_ws.Range("B1:B50")
            Set p_TenderValues = p_ws.Range("C1:C50")
        Case "Type2":
            Set p_LineDescriptions = p_ws.Range("C3:C53")
            Set p_TenderValues = p_ws.Range("D3:D53")
        Case Else:
            'Do nothing; ensure error handling when retrieving the properties though!
    End Select
End Property
Public Property Get LineDescriptions() As Range
    Set LineDescriptions = p_LineDescriptions
End Property
Public Property Get TenderValues() As Range
    Set TenderValues = p_TenderValues
End Property
```

Which will allow you to do the following:

```
Sub Test()
Dim RR As RangeReturner
Dim c As Range

Set RR = New RangeReturner
RR.SheetToCheck = Worksheets("Type1-Somesheet")

'And you'll now be able to do something like:

For Each c In RR.LineDescriptions
    Debug.Print c.value
Next c

Set RR = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This approach looks like it will work for what i need. Thanks very much for your help and detailed response. I like the 'case else' to prevent range errors. I normally just use an error handler statement but these can be difficult to identify the specific problem. I have rated your answer but don't have the reputation score for it to show here

Comment: If it works and solves the problem, consider marking the question answered instead. :)